# What happens if I turn off registrar lock for my domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

Does that mean anyone can steal it and I will have to kiss my domain name goodbye?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anyone can steal it. It just means you can  transfer it to another registrar if you'd like to. Registrar lock exists as an extra ;layer of protection against domain theft but it isn't required for your domain to be secure.

Comment: If _I'd_ like to or if _anyone_ would like to?

Comment: If you would like to.

Comment: So, what am I at risk of exactly if I leave registrar lock off?

Comment: Not much really. It's makes transferring your domain possible which means it is technically possible for someone who is creative to transfer your domain but it still requires a lot of errors by you and your registrar for that to happen which is about as likely as a meteor hitting you in the head today. Possible, but very unlikely.

Comment: lol, oh. I'm under the impression that by "someone who it creative" you mean someone who's good at hacking. What type of errors might you be thinking of?